# update manifest of a kubernetes object

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, metrics-server

I have a k8s cluster and I have to update `metrics-server` (in the `kube-system`) namespace. I've tried to:

```
kubectl apply -n kube-system -f my-updated-metrics-server.yaml
```

and

```
kubectl replace -n kube-system -f my-updated-metrics-server.yaml
```

without success. What happens is that the deployment gets updated but then after a while (10-15 min), it gets to the previous status (before the `apply`/`replace` commands).

any thoughts?

UPDATED (as requested)

```
$ kubectl get ns |grep -iE 'argo|flux'
$
```

Comment: can you add output of `kubectl get ns |grep -iE 'argo|flux'` to the question ?

Comment: done. but what is that for?

Comment: Looking for namespaces matching `argo` and `flux` doesn't tell you whether or not the cluster is managed using one of these tools -- e.g., we manage multiple clusters with a single instance of ArgoCD, so there's no "argocd" namespace on any of the managed clusters. And on the cluster actually running ArgoCD, the namespace is "openshift-gitops". That's all just a long-winded way of saying that it *looks* as if your deployment may be managed using some automated tooling; do you know how it was originally applied? Do you have any sort of CD/gitops workflow that deploys manifests to your cluster?

Comment: @larsks makes sense; I did some oversight here

Comment: oh yes, I use helm chart @larks

Comment: A helm chart won't normally cause automatic replacement...unless you have some sort of automated workflow that is re-deploying the chart periodically. But if you're deploying with a Helm chart, you're generally better off updating the chart and re-installing it rather than trying to patch the generated resources.